# Odd space at the top of grouped UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm getting an odd space at the top of my tableview inside a regular UIViewController. I've tried to uncheck Adjust Scroll View insets, setting Content Insets to never, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grouped tableviews use a fixed height section header and footer views even if you're not using them. Try to return a very small number in your viewForHeaderInSection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0001
}
```

Comment: I'm using both the header and footer in each section.

Comment: And the problem only occurs at the top of the tableview.